# How to add multiple cart items in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce, cart

I want to insert cart items into database but when I insert data it will insert just a single product so how to insert multiple products at once

Comment: what code you have tried so far ?

Comment: this is my controller:

Comment: function form_insert($data){

$this->db->insert('place_order', $data);
}

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem There is a edit button below tag's you may click on that and edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->db->insert_batch();`

**Example**

Your record data should be array format

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);
```

Now pass the set of data to the following function

```
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data );
```

Simple use following function for your case, it will help you. add this function to your model file

```
public function insertAllQuery($table, $valueArray){
        $this->db->insert_batch($table, $valueArray);
        return ($this->db->trans_status()) ? true : false;
    }
```

pass the card items in a controller as like below

```
$this->your_model->insertAllQuery('table_name', $data );
```

Comment: please give positive feedback to the answer. so, it will help other people too find the solution. Thanks.